# Ssh login/shell not completely working (as before)

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I am logging in with ssh to a linux terminal (Ubuntu 16.04), but the shell is not completely 'working' anymore. What I mean with that is:

- I am able to login
- I am not able to use the arrow keys to go back to a previously used command. Using the 'up' arrow just prints `^[[A` on the shell
- The shell consists of the sign `$`only (before it was a shell with the computer name or something).

I have not changed anything in the `.bashrc` file as far s I know. How to get my 'normal' shell back...?

Content of `SHELL` is `/bin/sh`. Changing it to `/bin/bash` and tlogin does not change behavior.

Comment: Changing the `SHELL` variable isn't going to have an effect on the current shell; check your account's actual login shell (`getent passwd $USER` on the server) and adjust if necessary using `chsh -s /bin/bash`

Comment: Yes that worked, please answer with the `chsh` idea, so I can accept your input as answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the `SHELL` variable isn't going to have an effect on the current shell or on subsequent logins.

The shell whose behaviour you describe is the Debian Almquist shell, which does not have line editing and [which has been the shell named by `/bin/sh` by default on Ubuntu since 2006](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh).

Check your account's actual login shell (`getent passwd $USER` on the server) and adjust if necessary using `chsh -s /bin/bash` (or `chsh -s /bin/zsh` or `chsh -s /bin/ksh93` or `chsh -s /usr/bin/fish` or whatever interactive shell you want to use).